# Widget testing Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart, widget-test-flutter

I am doing widget testing but I got `Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.`. How can I fix this error?

fvm flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.12 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d9e56e694 (3 months ago) • 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();

  const testWidget = MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: CommitteeHubView(),
    ),
  );
  testWidgets("CommitteeHubView", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(testWidget);

    expect(find.text('Committee Hub'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

: Error: The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
rm.dart:2127

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  framework.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.

  ```
      _contextSet.last.mounted ? _contextSet.last.findRenderObject() : null;
                       ^^^^^^^
  ```

Failed to load "/Users/jaehyuckchoi/Desktop/resvu/untitled folder/communitilink_flutter_app/test/view/committee_hub/committee_hub_view_test.dart": Compilation failed for testPath=/Users/jaehyuckchoi/Desktop/resvu/untitled folder/communitilink_flutter_app/test/view/committee_hub/committee_hub_view_test.dart

✖ loading /Users/jaehyuckchoi/Desktop/resvu/untitled folder/communitilink_flutter_app/test/view/committee_hub/committee_hub_view_test.dart
Exited (1)